# calling bash functions with arguments that have to be quoted

Tags: bash, functions

How can I handle the calling of functions that take arguments that have to be quoted?

For instance, consider the following function

```
time-stamp ()
 {
  if (( $# == 0)); then
    tmstamp="$(date +T%T.%N)"
  else
    tmstamp="$(date $1)"
  fi
  echo "$tmstamp"
 }
```

Here are some calling possibilities

```
var="+%T %N"
stamp=$( date "${var}" )
```

or

```
var="+%T %N"
stamp="$( date "${var}" )"
```

Comment: You don't use the function in the calling possibilities. Have you tried both the approaches? What were the results and how were they different to your expectations?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Do I need to quote command substitutions when assigning their output to a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362130/do-i-need-to-quote-command-substitutions-when-assigning-their-output-to-a-variab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construct `$(some_commands ...)` is called command substitution.

The difference between your two examples is in treatment of the command substitution result not in the parameter(s) of the command. (Note: You could also put a shell function or an alias in the place of the command.)

#### Shell substitution result processing

Shell performs word/field splitting and filename expansion on the result of the command substitution. If you want to prevent these changes then enclose the construct between double quotes like you did in the second example:

```
var="+%T %N"
stamp="$( date "${var}" )"
```

If you do not do that, shell will split the result to words/field by whitespace separators and/or perform filename expansion on wildcard characters like `*`, `?`, `[]`. You should use double quotes there unless you want the shell to do the modifications.

#### Exception and demonstration

The assignment is an exception. POSIX shell (including bash) does not perform the word splitting and filename expansion on the variable assignment:<sup>[1](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01)</sup>

```
$ printf '<%s>' $(echo 'a    b') ; echo
<a><b>
$ x=$(echo 'a    b')
$ printf '<%s>' "$x" ; echo
<a    b>
```

```
$ touch file1 file2
$ printf '<%s>' $(echo '*') ; echo
<file1><file2>
$ x=$(echo '*')
$ printf '<%s>' "$x" ; echo
<*>
```

Notice that in the first example the variable `x` does contain the complete string `a    b` (including the four spaces) so it was not split in the assignment. Using quotes in such cases does not change the result but you can use them to keep the good habit.